# \leftarrow does not work

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am trying to write a document in which for some reason some of the things like `\overleftarrow{example}` works but `\leftarrow` and `\rightarrow` etc. does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't work as in "doesn't compile" or doesn't work as in "doesn't produce an arrow" or what?

Comment: How exactly don't they work? Do you get an error or do they just not show up?

Comment: @blahdiblah: Heh, we asked exactly the same question within 10 seconds of each other.

Comment: I get an error I think something about not being in math mode ? ! Missing $ inserted. it says

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250522/latex-leftarrow-does-not-work?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Even thought it may seem trivial, it is _always_ best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  I suspect, that in this case your problem could have been isolated much quicker if one had been provided.

Answer (score 21):

`\leftarrow` is a math mode symbol.  Try `$\leftarrow$` if you're using it inline in regular text.

Comment: ah so thats what missing $ means after all.. thanks it worked. How do I switch to math mode ?

Comment: Math mode just means that the part of the document you're working on is an equation. `$abc$` means the `abc` is in math mode. You can also use `\(\)`; things like `\[\]` and the various math environments (equation, align...etc) also put their contents into math mode but also have other effects.

Comment: Using `$`s is one way, but there are others.  Have a look at, e.g., http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/tex/course/intro2.html for more information about LaTeX's various modes.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: It sounds like you're not in math mode when you're trying to insert the arrows. If you're already in an equation, you might be using a command that makes a box. Try surrounding the arrow commands with `$` or `\( \)`.

Comment: still doest work but just discovered that  \ensuremath{\leftarrow} works but dont know how I can do that with out  \ensuremath tag

Comment: It sounds like you might be having issues with math mode. Are you trying to put the arrows inside some sort of box?

Comment: trying to use them in an \enumarate along with an \item

Comment: As I said, you need to be in math mode. Try using `$\rightarrow$` or `\(\rightarrow\)` when you want an arrow.